# Boost 1.53 and 1.58 difference

Tags: c++, boost

Following is a small and simple piece of code I wrote :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

        fs::directory_iterator it((fs::path(argv[1])));
        fs::directory_iterator endit;

        while(it != endit)
        {
                cout<<it->path().string()<<endl;
                ++it;
        }
}
```

I then wrote a very simple CMakeLists.txt file as follows :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

When I compile this code on OS X Yosemite, it runs perfectly.

The compiler details are as follows :

```
$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

I then ran it on a Fedora 19 system and it did produce errors during compilation. The error message is very long. My project involves a number of source files, but for this problem, a part of the error message is sufficient to understand the problem :

```
/user/uujjwal/home/code/pom-final/test/abc.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
/user/uujjwal/home/code/pom-final/test/abc.cpp:13:10: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(boost::filesystem::path*)' and 'boost::filesystem::directory_iterator')
  while(it!=endit)
```

Thus it shows that the operator != is invalid.

The compiler details on Fedora system are :

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-20131017/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-20131017/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 20131017 (Red Hat 4.8.2-1) (GCC)
```

Boost version on OS X - 1.58
Boost version on Fedora System - 1.53

I want to know that is this owing to a fundamental difference between the two versions ? Is the reason something else ? If I have to make some changes in the code, to make it portable, what is the right way ?

****PS :-I also noticed out of experimentation that on Fedora if , do the following**

```
 fs::path root_path(argv[1]);
    fs::directory_iterator it(root_path);
```

it then compiles. So where is the difference coming and why ?**

Comment: It compiles both with 1_53/1_58. And with both GNU c++03 and c++11. And also with clang-3.5 both versions and language modes.

Comment: I don't see that error using Boost 1.53 and GCC 4.8.2, are you sure you get that error for that example code?

Comment: 100%. I checked thrice and even got it checked by 3 other people in my lab. All of them confirmed that the code is  absolutely the same and that the error is coming exactly as I have written on the question.

Answer (score 5):

The LHS operand type in your error message is `boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(boost::filesystem::path*)`. This indicates that you're experiencing a most vexing parse error; the declaration of `it` is being parsed as a function declaration rather than a local variable declaration-instantiation:

```
    fs::directory_iterator it(fs::path(argv[1]));
```

This is parsed as the declaration of an extern function named `it`, taking one argument (named `argv`) of type `fs::path[1]` (`fs::path*` after decay) and returning `fs::directory_iterator`.

What's odd is that your extra parentheses should have prevented the MVP error. Either your version of gcc is buggy and ignored them, or something changed between the code you're presenting and what was passed to the compiler.

```
    fs::directory_iterator it((fs::path(argv[1])));
    // extra parentheses      ^                 ^ to prevent MVP
```

Comment: Seems a probable explanation. But I assure you, I checked it thrice. and absolutely nothing was different in the 2 versions of the code or CMake on the two systems. Even the CMake used was the same version. 
Though my P.S part has solved my problem. But I am still in a fix about this behavior.

Comment: @UjjwalAryan must be a compiler bug then; the extra parentheses trick is a well-documented way to fix MVP. Alternatives are intermediate declaration as you've mentioned, `static_cast`, or C++11 uniform initialization (curly braces).